# New codes prevent old codes from working?

Tags: excel, vba

This Excel file tracks engine status from Sales and Production departments. Columns A - M in the workbook contain data necessary to deem the engine status. Columns N - AS are used to track engine status with the following column order: Sales, Production, Day 1, Status. That repeats till Day 8 (i.e. Sales, Production, Day 8, Status).

Those 8 Days represent the last 8 days of the month and data gets updated to columns A-M every day during that period. However,let's say it's the 2nd day today, though the data is very likely to get updated in columns A - M, data in Day 1's columns (Sales, Production, Day 1, Status) stay the same. Then, we continue on putting down status for Day 2.

And here is my problem, I was trying to get the Macro to do: **If "Shipped" in column AV, then the empty remaining Days will have "Rollup" in both Sales and Production columns**.

Can you please advise why after adding the following lines to Master Worksheet, the Macro no longer returns values in Day columns (per the IF statements from Module) though it did before adding those codes?

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim counter As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

' Check if header is "MB51 Shipped"
If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "MB51 Shipped" Then

    ' Get last column based on first row
    lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Check all cells in row and find matches for Sales and Production
    For counter = 1 To lastColumn

        ' Check if header match and cell is not empty
        If (Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Sales" or Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Production") And Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = vbNullString Then

            Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Rollup"

        End If

    Next counter

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Thank you! And my apology for putting a lot of codes down here since someone has advised not to include a Macro enabled link.

Here is what I currently have in my Master Worksheet tab:

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim r As Range, r1 As Range

        Dim lastColumn As Long
        Dim counter As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Check if header is "MB51 Shipped"
    If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "MB51 Shipped" Then

        ' Get last column based on first row
        lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' Check all cells in row and find matches for Sales and Production
        For counter = 1 To lastColumn

            ' Check if header match and cell is not empty
            If (Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Sales" Or Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Production") And Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = vbNullString Then

                Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "Rollup"

            End If

        Next counter

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

        Set r = Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Columns(colSales1).Resize(, 3))
        If Not r Is Nothing Then Call DoCells(r)

    End Sub


    Private Sub DoCells(r As Range)
        Dim r1 As Range
        For Each r1 In r.Cells
            With r1
                Select Case .Column
                    Case colSales1
                        Call MasterChange(.Resize(1, 3))
                    Case colProduction1
                        Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3))
                    Case colDay1
                        Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3))
                End Select
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
```

And this is on the Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const colSales1 As Long = 14
Public Const colProduction1 As Long = 15
Public Const colDay1 As Long = 16
Public Const colStatus1 As Long = 17

Sub UpdateMaster()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsSAP As Worksheet

    If MsgBox("Do you want to update 'Master Worksheet' from 'SAP'?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Update Master") = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wsMaster = Worksheets("Master Worksheet")
    Set wsSAP = Worksheets("SAP")

    'IMPORTANT -- turn off events
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'get rid of old data
    wsMaster.Cells.Clear

    'copy SAP
    wsSAP.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Cells(1, 1)

    'add formulas - double "" inside string to get one
    Set r = wsMaster.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(colStatus1)
    Set r = r.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count)
    r.Formula = "=IF(O2=N2,""Sales/Production"",IF(P2=O2,""Production"",IF(P2=N2,""Sales"","""")))"

    'IMPORTANT -- turn on events
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub ClearMaster()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("SampleReport03.xlsm").Sheets("Master Worksheet")
    ws.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).Clear
End Sub

Sub ClearSAP()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("SampleReport.xlsm").Sheets("SAP")
    ws.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
End Sub


Public Sub MasterChange(SPD As Range)
    Dim rSales As Range
    Dim rProduction As Range
    Dim rDay As Range

    Set rSales = SPD.Cells(1, 1)
    Set rProduction = SPD.Cells(1, 2)
    Set rDay = SPD.Cells(1, 3)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Rollup" Then
        rDay = "Rollup"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Green" Then
        rDay = "Green"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Yellow" Then
        rDay = "Yellow"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Red" Then
        rDay = "Red"
    ElseIf rSales = "Rollup" And rProduction = "Overdue" Then
        rDay = "Overdue"
    ElseIf rSales = " " And rProduction = " " Then
        rDay.ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Here is what in my spreadsheet:

```html
| Title  | Engine   Family  | Market Segment | Customer | Engine Model | S/N | Build Spec | ACTL.FINISH | Sales Order | Item  | Committed Date | EPS Date   | Target    | Sales | Production | Day 1  | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 2 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 3 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 4 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 5 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 6 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 7 | Status           | Sales  | Production | Day 8 | Status           | Status           | Comments | MB51 Shipped | FPS? | Plant | Title Transfer |
|--------|------------------|----------------|----------|--------------|-----|------------|-------------|-------------|-------|----------------|------------|-----------|-------|------------|--------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|--------|------------|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|--------------|------|-------|----------------|
| Rollup | PS               | APU            | HAC      | T-62T-46C12  | 1   | BS1        | 0000-00-00  | 0           | 0     | 2019/12/31     | 2019/12/31 | Rollup    | Green | Yellow     | Yellow | Production       | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Rollup | Rollup     |       | Sales/Production | Sales/Production |          | Shipped      |      |       |                |
| Rollup | PS               | APU            | SA       | S2300        | 2   | BS2        | 2019/06/25  | 1           | 380   | 2019/06/24     | 2019/06/25 | Available |       |            |        | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production | Sales/Production |          |              |      |       |                |
| Yellow | PS               | APU            | AOG      | PS3200       | 3   | BS3        | 0000-00-00  | 2           | 1     | 2019/12/16     | 2019/12/20 | Yellow    |       |            |        | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production |        |            |       | Sales/Production | Sales/Production |          |              |      |       |                |
```

As you can see, after entering status in Column N, O, my macro did return `Yellow` with no trouble or error. Then I put `Shipped` in column AV, the Macro did automatically return `Rollup` for both Production and Sales columns, however, Macro no longer worked in Day columns.

Please let me know if you need more info and thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Please do not include a link to your macro-enabled file. It is unlikely anyone will download it as that can be dangerous.

Comment: @braX Hi, thank you for the advice. I've edited the post with all necessary codes. Thanks again

Comment: You may want to look at creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will make it easier for everyone to find the problem (and, who knows? in the process you may find it yourself)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad hi, I can definitely create a mcve, however, it's still a macro-enabled workbook isn't it? Then, it's what braX has recommended against. Sorry, I'm new here. Please advise. Thank you

Comment: I mean [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60267376/edit) to only post the relevant parts of the code in your question instead of 200+ lines.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks again. I've edited the post.

Comment: The initial explanation of what your code _does_ indicates that you are looking for "Shipped".  But the code example is trying to match "MB51 Shipped".

Comment: @BZngr Hi, someone helped me with that piece of codes and I believed he was trying to check if the column's name is "MB51 Shipped" because column AV is named "MB51 Shipped". The only question I have is why after adding the codes, my Day columns didn't return any value (they did before)

Comment: Do you have some sample data?  Have had a look through the code and can see that `r` is set at the end of the `Worksheet_Change` event, this is used in `DoCells` which in turn calls `MasterChange` which then does stuff dependant on the value of `rSales` and `rProduction`.  Gets a bit difficult to follow it all without data to compare it against.  You can use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to format your data into tables that can be pasted into your question (and formatted as code).

Comment: Hi @DarrenBartrup-Cook , thank you very much for the suggestion. I've added my data in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes below restore the lost functionality (as I understand it from your comments).  There are comments to describe what & why the changes were made.

```
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim r As Range, r1 As Range

        Dim lastColumn As Long
        Dim counter As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Get last column based on first row
    '*** Need to set lastColumn outside of the Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).value = "MB51 Shipped" statement
    '*** so that the Intersect function does not fail (blow-up) if a cell in a column other than "MB51 Shipped" is modified .
    '*** Perhaps the Intersect call belongs within the If statement?
    lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Check if header is "MB51 Shipped"
    If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).value = "MB51 Shipped" Then

        ' Get last column based on first row
        'lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' Check all cells in row and find matches for Sales and Production
        For counter = 1 To lastColumn

            ' Check if header match and cell is not empty
            If (Me.Cells(1, counter).value = "Sales" Or Me.Cells(1, counter).value = "Production") And Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).value = vbNullString Then

                Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).value = "Rollup"

            End If

        Next counter

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
        '***In the posted code, The Intersect() function was never returning a non-null Range
        '***I think your intent was to find the intersection of the colSales1 column and the Target row
        'Set r = Intersect(Target, Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, Columns(colSales1).Resize(, 3))

        '*** This Intersect() call provides the range that I think you intended
        Set r = Intersect(Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, lastColumn)), Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion)

        If Not r Is Nothing Then Call DoCells(r)

    End Sub

    '*** DoCells was only attempting to operate on three columns, colSales1, colProduction1, and colDay1
    '*** And...each of the Case statements is sending the same range to MasterChange -> so, it was doing the same operation 3 times
    '*** I believe the intent was to call each Sales/Production/Days group and update...so, replacing the Select Case with
    '*** the following if statement updates all the Sales/Production/Days groups.
    Private Sub DoCells(r As Range)
        Dim r1 As Range
        For Each r1 In r.Cells
            With r1
                'Find each "Sales" column.  Call MasterChange only once for each group
                If Me.Cells(1, colSales1).value = r1.Offset(-1, 0).value Then
                    MasterChange .Resize(1, 3)
                End If
                'Select Case .Column
                '    Case colSales1
                '        Call MasterChange(.Resize(1, 3))
                '    Case colProduction1
                '        Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3))
                '    Case colDay1
                '        Call MasterChange(.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 3))
                'End Select
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @BZngr thank you for the detailed explanation and codes. The `Shipped` thing works great now, however, there's now a problem with my IF statements. My Day columns wouldn't return any values except those that Sales and Production cells have Rollup and Rollup status. Any other cells were all blank when I entered their Sales and Production status. Do you know why? Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: @JaneH I think this is a far as I can help given the information provided.  At this point I would recommend you remove my changes from your original code since it causes as loss of other functionality.  Once that is done, I would recommend that you remove the "new codes that prevented the old codes from working" - and verify that the old(original) code still works as you expect.  Then, introduce your new code (incrementally if  possible), troubleshooting as you go.